# How to remove space between highChart bar graph between two different category

Tags: highcharts

read the comment in jsfiddle.
The space should not be there in rendered graph between blue one and green one in c1
http://www.jsfiddle.net/QnU9e/1/

In bar graph making 2 category and 3 series

```
series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [49.5, 71.5]

    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data: [null, 78.8] // The space should not be there in rendered graph between blue one and green one in c1

    }, {
        name: 'c',
        data: [30, 78.8]

    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can find to do this is to control the bar spacing yourself by specifying X data values.  Note, I set the `pointPadding: 0` in the `plotOptions` so I could get total control.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [[0.075,49.5], [1,71.5]]

    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data: [[0,null], [1.025,78.8]]// The space should not be there in rendered graph between blue one and green one in c1

    }, {
        name: 'c',
        data: [[-0.075,30], [1.05,78.8]]

    }]
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnU9e/3/).

[image]

Comment: That is a hell of a hack...
This require a lot of data manipulation and adding lot of meta data

Comment: @user2410148, agreed it's a hack.  Best I could come up with though within the bounds of the Highcharts API.

Answer (score 0):

Uforutnatley this options is not supported, but you can try to manipulate columns by translate() function which allows ot move SVG elements.